# combine django user with many-to-many model for display organized by user and other fields

Tags: django, django-templates, django-queryset, manytomanyfield

I have a django model that represents a calendar event:

```
class Event(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
   date = models.DateField(default=default_event_date)
   category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
   users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='events',
                                          limit_choices_to={'is_staff': True})
   ...
```

How can I get a queryset from this model and organize the data so that I can display it (in a template) something like this:

```
       Date1         Date2         Date3         Date4      ...
User1  CatA (Title1) CatC (Title4) CatB (Title7) -
User2  CatD (Title2) CatB (Title5  -             CatD (Title9)
User3  CatC (Title3) CatC (Title4) CatC (Title8) CatC (Title10)
User4  -             -             -           -
User5  -             CatA (Title6) -             CatD (Title9)
...
```

Where DateN is the `date` field, UserN is the `users` field, and CatX is the `category` field, and TitleN is the `title`.